# Sort in Google Table Chart

Tags: google-visualization

I just want to sort the column 0 descending. I am using this code:

```
var table = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
  chartType: 'Table',
  containerId: 'chart_table_a',
  options: {
    sortColumn: 0,
    sortAscending: false,
    sort: 'enable'
  }
});
```

I don't want to make the table sortable, but the code only works with `sort: 'enable'`.

Is there a way to just sort without make the table sortable?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sort your DataTable:

```
// sort by column 0, descending
data.sort({column: 0, desc: true});
```

or use a sorted DataView:

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setRows(data.getSortedRows({column: 0, desc: true}));
table.draw(view, options);
```

Sorting the DataTable modifies the actual order of the data, and will affect other charts/tables that use the DataTable.  This can be expensive in terms of CPU usage if the DataTable contains a large number of rows.  Using a DataView preserves the data in the original DataTable (at the expense of a small increase in memory use), and is comparatively cheap in terms of CPU time, but if your DataTable isn't huge or you don't have any other charts that rely on it, you're probably safe just sorting the base DataTable.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I just updated the code, because I was using the table as part of a dashboard. In this case, how can I use one of your solutions?

Comment: You can still sort the base DataTable (or create a sorted DataView to drive your Dashboard).  If you have other charts that depend on a specific sort order, and you want to change the sort order just for the Table, then this becomes a bit trickier.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The only reason for not let the user sort is: When the user sort the table it lost the custom css applied (I will start another question with that situation).